# Get input from button

Tags: java, swing

I have a program that receives input from command line before. Now I want to make the GUI using Java Swing. Supposed I have a program with flow such as below:

```
while(!end){
    in = getInputFromUser();
    /*Value can be 1,2, or 3*/

    Execute(in);

    /* Do something else */

    end = isEndCondition();
}
```

How can I get the input by using three buttons instead?

Comment: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your GUI should work, you would typically use an actionListener definied on a button. Here is a complete example (including a text field) from the Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives an example of how to generate your three buttons. Add an action listener to the buttons using the Oracle documentation linked by @User404

```
public Buttons(){
    guiFrame = new JFrame();
    guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    guiFrame.setTitle("Buttons");
    guiFrame.setSize(300,300);
    guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));   
    guiFrame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    for (int i=1;i<4;i++)
    { 
        addNumberButton(buttonPanel, String.valueOf(i));
    }
    guiFrame.setVisible(true);  
}
private void addNumberButton(Container parent, String name)
{
    JButton but = new JButton(name);
    but.setActionCommand(name);
    but.addActionListener(this);
    parent.add(but);
}
```